# How does count work when passing an empty string?

Tags: python

I have a question, if I have

```
h = "hello world"
print (h.count(''))
```

That prints 12.

But if i do

```
print (h[11])
```

I get an **IndexError: string index out of range**

I don't understand the reason.

What does the count function count when passing an empty string?

Comment: Empty strings exist at both ends of your string, and between each pair of characters within it: so the result is the string length plus one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it prints 12 is that there are empty strings in between every letter, and at both sides. Here is a diagram:

```
  All empty strings!
^h^e^l^l^o^ ^w^o^r^l^d^
```

it looks weird, but every `^` is an empty sn empty string, and if you count them, there are 12.

The reason you are getting the error is that a string is just an array of characters, so it is zero-indexed, meaning that the first element is index 0, the second at index 1, and so on. Here is a diagram:

```
-------------------------------------
a | b | c | d | e | f | g | h | i | j
-------------------------------------
0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9
-------------------------------------
```

As you can see, the tenth element (`j`), is at index 9, so trying to get index 10 would result in an error.

Answer (score 0):

The String `Hello World` Can only be indexed up to 10.  Remember that indexes start at zero

H the first character is 0
and d at the end is 10

when you do `count('')`, it includes a blank space after and before the String, so it adds two extra increments.

So you can do `len(h)-1` or (`h.count('')-2`) to show the last element of the strings index.

Note len() shows how many elements are in a list not the index of the last one. The last element of a string or list is `len()-1`